# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'phone' of null at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function that get all client from api:

```
  this.ws.getallclients().subscribe(
  client => {
    this.client = client.map((clients) => {
      this.filteredOptions = this.addsale.controls['client_id'].valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(val => this._filter(val))
      );
      return new Client(clients);
    });
    if (this.ss.getData('client_id')) {
      const client_id = this.ss.getData('client_id');
      this.addsale.controls.client_id.setValue(client_id)
      let selectedClient = new Client('')
      this.selectedClient = null;
      for (let i = 0; i < client.length; i++) {
        if (client[i].client_id === client_id) {
          this.selectedClient = client[i];
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

In this show error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'phone' of null     at
>   Object.eval [as updateRenderer]

because client[i].client_id return client_id like 123456 ===  and client_id show name of client like MyName
and this html code:

My html code:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Client Data</legend>
        <div class="input-field col s4">
        <input formControlName="client_id" id="client_id"   matInput placeholder="Select Client*" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" >
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="onSelect(item.client_id)" *ngFor="let item of filteredOptions | async" [value]="item.name">
        {{item.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</div>
   <div class="input-field col s12">
    ID Number:
     <span style="color:darkblue">{{selectedClient.phone}}</span>
     </div>
 </fieldset>
```

Any idea how to issue this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your code sets `this.selectedClient = null` if there is no selected client and then your template tries to access `selectedClient.phone`, causing the error.  Maybe you intended to replace these lines:

```
  let selectedClient = new Client('')
  this.selectedClient = null;
```

with:

```
  this.selectedClient = new Client('')
```

so that you have a blank `Client` object in this situation.  Or maybe you want to use `ngIf` to avoid evaluating the problematic part of the template if there is no `selectedClient`.  I don't know Angular, but based on a quick read of the documentation, this might work:

```
<span *ngIf="selectedClient" style="color:darkblue">{{selectedClient.phone}}</span>
```